# What does one enter on the command line to run spark in a bokeh serve app? Do I simply separate the two command line entries by &&?

Tags: pyspark, bokeh, dask, dask-distributed

My effort does not work:
/usr/local/spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 6g --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.2 runspark.py && bokeh serve --show bokeh_app

runspark.py contains the instantiation of spark, and bokeh_app is the folder  of the bokeh server app. spark is being used to update  a streaming dask dataframe.

WHAT HAPPENS:
The spark instance starts running, loads as it normally would without the bokeh server. However as soon as the bokeh server app kicks in (i.e.) the  web page opens, the spark instance shuts down. It doesn't send back any errors in the console output. 
OUTPUT BELOW:

2018-11-26 21:04:05 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4f0492c9{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  StateStoreCoordinatorRef:54 - Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  AbstractConnector:318 - Stopped Spark@4f3c4272{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4041}
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  SparkUI:54 - Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.25:4041
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:54 - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2018-11-26 21:04:06 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2018-11-26 21:04:07 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2018-11-26 21:04:07 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2018-11-26 21:04:07 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-11-26 21:04:07 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-c42ce0b3-d49e-48ce-962c-277b42166267
2018-11-26 21:04:07 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bd448b2e-6b0f-467a-9e43-689542c42a6f
2018-11-26 21:04:07 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bd448b2e-6b0f-467a-9e43-689542c42a6f/pyspark-117d2a10-7cb9-4eb3-b4d0-f92f9046522c
2018-11-26 21:04:08,542 Starting Bokeh server version 0.13.0 (running on Tornado 5.1.1)
2018-11-26 21:04:08,547 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/aion_analytics
2018-11-26 21:04:08,547 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 10769

Comment: What does "does not work" mean, exactly? You need to provide more details, screenshots, etc, for others to be able to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. The idea is simply to embed the bokeh server in the pyspark code instead of running the bokeh server from the command line. Use the pyspark submit command as normal.

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.0.1/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py

I did exactly what shown in the link above.